# Multiple ISR's in msp430

Tags: embedded, msp430

I am coding msp430g2553 ussing CCS 5.5 . I have two interrupts enabled in my code. I am not able to understand how should i go about writing two different ISR for these two interrupts. How should i indicate in my code, which ISR corresponds to which interrupt.
Can anybody help me out with the syntax for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [MSP430 Optimizing C/C++ Compiler v 4.4 User's Guide](http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/slau132j/slau132j.pdf) it appears you can achieve this is one of three ways:

**Using GCC `__attribute__` syntax:**

```
#define TIMER_A0 20
volatile int tick = 0 ;
__attribute__((interrupt(TIMER_A0))) void tick_isr() 
{
    tick++ ;
}
```

**Using `__interrupt` + `#pragma vector`:**

```
#define TIMER_A0 20
volatile int tick = 0 ;
#pragma vector=TIMER_A0
__interrupt void tick_isr( void )
{
    tick++ ;
}
```

**Using `#pragma interrupt` + `#pragma vector`:**

```
#define TIMER_A0 20
volatile int tick = 0 ;
#pragma interrupt( tick_isr )
#pragma vector=TIMER_A0
void tick_isr( void )
{
    tick++ ;
}
```

The GCC syntax is probably simplest.  Note that the syntax for `#pragma interrupt` is different in C++ code:

```
#pragma interrupt
#pragma vector=TIMER_A0
void tick_isr( void )
{
    tick++ ;
}
```

Comment: do u also have knowledge about programming in energia??

Comment: I don't even have knowledge of programming MSP430 in CCS - I just know how to read a manual! ;-)